# Traversing a uer table and generating emails automatically

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, gmail

I have an RDS DB on AWS, it has your basic user table with first name, last name, and an email address. 
My company needs to send out a mass email, our servers or basically an alias for gmail.
My question is : 
How can I build a template email, that will get sent out from gmail, but by traversing the user table on RDS and inputting into that mass email first name , last name, and putting the email address in the to box of the email?

Comment: what flavor of rds? sql server, postgres? be a bit more specific

Comment: Good point, I am actually open to any implementation whatever is easier and less buggy

Comment: which one are you using though? theres a difference between SQL Server which you would use `sqlcmd` for and Postgres which you would use `psql` for and whatever other flavors they offer

Comment: The database hasn’t been built yet, so it’s open , i am asking this question o figure it best strategy.

Comment: database doesn't really matter, this question is too open ended in that case if you're asking someone to build a whole script but yes you can do this all from the shell, you'll also need `mutt` to send the email and to be configured properly

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of simple and powerful tools out there that can send bulk emails for you - [AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/introducing-email-templates-and-bulk-sending/), MailChimp, Campaign Monitor, AutopilotHQ, and a few others.